# OAuth2 client - using client-password with AddAccessTokenManagement

Tags: c#, rest, http, oauth-2.0, client

I'm using the `IdentityModel.Client` to create the HTTP client, which is using the OAuth authentication with grant-type `client-credentials`. How can I implement something similar to use the `client-password`? I don't see such option in `options.Client.Clients.Add` method - it supports only `ClientCredentialsTokenRequest`. I just don't want to create anything custom, if something standard exists :) Most of the samples use the `client-credentials`, or  just show how to create the server, not client.

```
        services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
        {
            options.Client.Clients.Add("identityserver", new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
            {
                Address = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.Address,
                ClientId = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.ClientSecret,
                Scope = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.Scope, // optional
                GrantType = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.GrantType
            });
        });

        services.AddClientAccessTokenHttpClient("client_oauth2", configureClient: client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.Address);
        });
```